# Why does this lose sort-order?

Tags: javascript, sorting, debugging

For the purposes of our frontend app, I need to ingest an array of objects (say about 20), then convert the array to a Key/Value object.

```
data = [
    {name: 'first', uid: 789, start: '2016-01-20 08:00:00'},
    {name: 'second', uid: 492, start: '2016-01-20 15:00:00'},
    {name: 'third', uid: 324, start: '2016-01-20 10:00:00'},
    {name: 'fourth', uid: 923, start: '2016-01-20 14:30:00'},
    // ...
];
```

I then run a sort on this the `start`

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aStart = new Date(a.start),
        bStart = new Date(b.start);

    if (aStart < bStart) return -1;
    if (aStart > bStart) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Then, for the purpose of quick-access to the data based on UID, I loop through this sorted array an convert it to a K/V Object:

```
var stored = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    stored[data[i].uid] = data[i];
}
```

This allows me to do something like `stored[uid]` instead of having to loop through `data` every time I need the index of a given object.

## Issue

In looping through and creating the `stored` Object, I seem to be losing the sort order.

## After Sorting:

```
2016-01-20 08:00:00 // 789
2016-01-20 10:00:00 // 324
2016-01-20 14:30:00 // 923
2016-01-20 15:00:00 // 492
```

## After converting to an Object

```
Object.keys(sorted).map(function (id, index) {
    console.log(sorted[id].start)
});
```

Yields:

```
2016-01-20 08:00:00 // 789
2016-01-20 14:30:00 // 923
2016-01-20 15:00:00 // 492
2016-01-20 10:00:00 // 324
```

As you can see, the 10AM event (`324`) is now at the end of the list and I am not sure as to why this happens.

Comment: JavaScript Objects are not guaranteed to maintain the order of insertion.

Comment: untrue, every implementation I can think of maintains insertion order. Can you post a more complete code example?

Comment: That's really all there is. There's no other manipulation of the ingested data involved. Taking @thefourtheye's comment into consideration, I was able to fix the sort order by first converting back to an array at render time and sorting it there.

Comment: @RobertMoskal no order is not guaranteed... That is why ES6 changed some things with new stuff. Object.keys() follows same order as for in loop. For in loop iterates in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

As thefourtheye says, while some engines do preserve the insertion order in objects, it is not a requirement. There are two ways to keep the order of properties:

- Keep an array of sorted keys; iterate on that array to access the object properties in order.

```js
var data = [
  {name: 'first', uid: 789, start: '2016-01-20 08:00:00'},
  {name: 'second', uid: 492, start: '2016-01-20 15:00:00'},
  {name: 'third', uid: 324, start: '2016-01-20 10:00:00'},
  {name: 'fourth', uid: 923, start: '2016-01-20 14:30:00'}
];

var stored = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  stored[data[i].uid] = data[i];
}

var keys = Object.keys(stored);
keys.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aStart = new Date(stored[a].start),
  var bStart = new Date(stored[b].start);

  if (aStart < bStart) return -1;
  if (aStart > bStart) return 1;
  return 0;
});

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(stored[key].start);
});
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

- Use ES6 `Map`, which is guaranteed to keep insertion order.

```js
var data = [
  {name: 'first', uid: 789, start: '2016-01-20 08:00:00'},
  {name: 'second', uid: 492, start: '2016-01-20 15:00:00'},
  {name: 'third', uid: 324, start: '2016-01-20 10:00:00'},
  {name: 'fourth', uid: 923, start: '2016-01-20 14:30:00'}
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aStart = new Date(a.start),
    bStart = new Date(b.start);

  if (aStart < bStart) return -1;
  if (aStart > bStart) return 1;
  return 0;
});

var stored = new Map();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  stored.set(data[i].uid, data[i]);
}

stored.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value.start);
});
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```